# How to install Eclipse latest version (Neon) on Ubuntu (CDT) and run NOT as superuser

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to upgrade eclipse to the latest version, neon.

I have downloaded the tar.gz and untarred it.
I open the directory and there is a file eclipse-inst.

If I don't run it as sudo it fails to install.
If I do run it as sudo it tries to set everything into areas for /root and then I can't access them later.

For example, I "pinned" the apparent "launcher" button but clicking it now achieves nothing.

The only way I can seem to get back is as a super-user.

Trying to run it otherwise gives me:

```
The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library`
```

I can run it with

```
sudo eclipse
```

but I don't want to have to run it as a super-user.

When trying to install on my own account I get:

> [2016-08-03 18:10:34] ERROR:
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read
>   repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon.
>   java.io.IOException: Permission denied   at
>   java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)   at
>   java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.updateCache(CacheManager.java:391)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCacheFromFile(CacheManager.java:132)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:56)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:78)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116) 
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:370)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:177)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:437)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1625)
>   at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:416)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Answer (score 1):

You must change user owner and permissions of the installer. If the problems persist, try the same on the installation folder and files:

```
sudo chown <yourUserName> <file>
sudo chown -R <yourUserName> <folder>
sudo chmod 0644 <file>
sudo chmod 0644 -R <folder>
```

Where `<yourUserName>` is your user name, and `<file/folder>`  the file or folder to process.

Try to install Eclipse on a separated folder in your Home folder, for example: `/home/$USER/Programs/Eclipse`

Comment: Firstly, the installer itself is in my own user name and owned by me. Secondly, I don't really want to install it under my home directory.